# DRY'ing up my application

Tags: codeigniter, oop, dry

I have `MY_Controller` as a parent class. It only loads the views, passing some data to them. My application is a simple website with few controllers extending `MY_Controller`, that are just setting some variables which contain info that needs to be passed to the views.

I have one controller which is just a little bit different then others. It needs to pass more info to the views that is taken from database. What should I do in that case?

As I see it, I can override the whole index function in that controller, but that violates DRY rule, because the only difference is setting few more values to my array that is passed to every view. Or I can write few more LOC in the parent controller, but I guess that is not a good practise, as that specific child controller is the only controller that needs that code.

I've been struggling with it for a while and would be glad if you could point me to the right direction, or give me some advice how to do this properly.

My controllers:

```
    class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
    {
        $style='',
        $contents = array(),
        $title=''; //and so on

        public function index()
        {
            $data['style'] = $this->style;
            $data['title'] = $this->title;

            $this->load->view('header',$data);

            foreach($this->contents as $row)
            {
                $this->load->view($row,$data);
            }

            $this->load->view('footer',$data);
        }
    }
```

Gallery controller so far

```
    class Gallery extends MY_Controller 
    {
        $style = 'galeria.css',
        $title = 'galeria',
        $contents = array('content_gallery');

        // if $gallery is null, show only all galleries in a list, 
        //else show chosen gallery with its content beneath that list
        public function index($gallery = NULL)
        {        
            $data['galleries'] = $this->gallery_model->get_all_active_galleries(); //names and ids

            if( $gallery != NULL )
            {
                $data['name'] = ...
                $data['description'] = ...

                etc...
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something for every method of a specific controller, but not for other controllers, then what you can do is override the constructor for that controller, as in this example:

```
class Main extends MY_Controller {

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        // Call the constructor of the parent controller
        parent::__construct();

        // Load the session library
        $this->load->library('session');
    }
}
?>
```

In this example, we want to load the session library for every method, so we override the constructor for this controller. We call the constructor first, then we load the session library.

The same principle applies to any other tasks you may want to do. However, bear in mind that any data you want to set in the constructor and use elsewhere in the controller needs to be set as an attribute of the model. For example, if you want to get all the products sold by a store from one of your models, you'd need to store it as `$this->products`, not `$products`.